# Change a value in an array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, I need to loop through and change it's value:

```
foreach ($input['qualification'] as &$_v) {
    $_v = ucwords($_v);
}
```

But this only works for the first item in the array. When I remove the ampersand it loops through the entire array, but obviously the changes are not made.

Comment: Can you print the array for us and paste

Comment: array:3 [
  0 => "sadf"
  1 => "safd"
  2 => "safd"
]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to apply a function to all of the values in an array I would recommend using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead.

> Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays

```
$qualifications = array_map('ucwords', $input['qualification']);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/436363)

Comment: Isn't that anonymous function extraneous? Could you instead do `array_map('ucwords', $input['qualification']);` (genuinely curious)

Comment: You're right. I'm so used to doing it with custom functions i overthought it.

Comment: Thanks, but this has no effect on the string in the array.

Comment: Can you post a sample array so a demo can be made?

Comment: This is the dump of the array: array:3 [
  0 => "sadf"
  1 => "safd"
  2 => "safd"
]

Comment: one more quick question, with array map, is it possible to use strtolower and then ucwords so something like: sTRING rest of sentence -> String rest of sentence?

Comment: Sure, you would need to write a custom callback to do both for you but that's very doable

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it more slowly, with explicit reference to the index, in case your actual programming task requires the value of the index.

https://eval.in/436395

```
$input = array('juggling','french','math');

foreach ($input as $i=>$v) {
    $input[$i] = ucwords($v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input['qualification'] = array('high school', 'inter school', 'bachelor of scinece', 'master of science');

foreach ($input['qualification'] as &$_v) {
    $_v = ucwords($_v);
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($input['qualification']);
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.) –